# ZConnection does not work with FB 2.1

Tags: delphi, firebird, zeos

)

I used to use Firebird 1.5.

It works great but I need to make an incremental backup so it looks to me that I need to updgrade FB to at least 2.1

This is what I did, I un-installed 1.5 and installed 2.1

Flamerobin works fine.

In my Delphi 7 application I use ZConnection version 6.6.6-stable. It worked fine with Protocol set to firebird-1.5 but with firebird-2.1 it crashes with `Access violation at address 000000000. Read of address 00000000`.

I do not want to update ZEOS libs because I am afraid that I will break something in the process.

I need incremental backup (so it seems to me that I need FB at least 2.1). I do not want FB 2.5 because my ZConnection highest protocol is only 2.1 (and it does not seem to be working).

Any ideas, help? What is the best solution here?

Thank you! :-)

Comment: Without seeing any code it's difficult to say, but upgrading the library would be the obvious thing to do. I'm not familiar with Zeos lib but from what you describe 2.1 support is broken in your version. Have you tried checking with the component's authors?

Comment: A client that talks the Firebird 2.1 protocol can also talk to Firebird 2.5 (actually all previous Firebird client versions work).

Comment: Looks like I need new version of library. Thank you guys.